# Cut off buttons on google sites

Tags: html, css, button

So I put in custom buttons on google sites, and they work fine on desktop, but get cut off on mobile. [cut off button on mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAIsd.png)
When I first put in the code for the buttons it gave me a scroll bar for the buttons on mobile, so i coded in to turn it off on mobile, which leaves me with cut off buttons.

```
<button id="my-button" class="custom-button" 
<button onlick="About"><a href="https://www.maryschiff.com/about" style="text-decoration:none; color:inherit">Get To Know Me</a></button>
<style>
.custom-button {
 display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f0dc09;

  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
font-family: 'Roboto Serif';
position: fixed; 


}

.custom-button:hover {
  background-color: blue; 
  color: white; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

</style>
```

I tried looking through this site and google in general but couldn't find any code that helped.